# Query for deeply nested array in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, multidimensional-array, nested

How do I query a deeply nested docs like show in the below image.

[image]

Here `columns` is an array of unknown size. Each element in the column contains a `record` that is again an array. Each element of the `record` array contains an array called `fields`. Each entry in the `field` contains 2 keys called `name` and `value`.

I'm querying the `name` of the innermost array (in fields array). I couldn't go above level 1 order of nesting.

JSON doc of the above image

```
"data" : {
        "columns" : [
            {
                "name" : "styleId", 
                "record" : [
                    {
                        "fname" : "column_mapping", 
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5ba488c79dc6d62c90257752"), 
                        "fields" : [
                            {
                                "name" : "column_mapping_form", 
                                "value" : "styleId"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "rules" : [
                            [

                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "vendorArticleNumber", 
                "record" : [
                    {
                        "fname" : "column_mapping", 
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5ba488c79dc6d62c90257753"), 
                        "fields" : [
                            {
                                "name" : "column_mapping_form", 
                                "value" : "vendorArticleNumber"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "rules" : [
                            [

                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "vendorArticleName", 
                "record" : [
                    {
                        "fname" : "column_mapping", 
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5ba488c79dc6d62c90257754"), 
                        "fields" : [
                            {
                                "name" : "column_mapping_form", 
                                "value" : "vendorArticleName"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "rules" : [
                            [

                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
}
```

What can be the solutions if such kind of heaving nesting is there?

Comment: Use don't notation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/ and avoid posting images when you can post a json document as code snippet.

Comment: I have added the json

Comment: Please give an example, am not able to go above 2 levels of nesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.collection.find("data.columns.record.fields.name" : "column_mapping_form")
```

will match all documents where there is at least one element of `columns` has at least one `record` with at least one `field` where `name` is "column_mapping_form".

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/ has very good explanation, examples, and interactive shell to play with.